# Understanding pack / unpack perl

Tags: perl, pack

so I know there are libraries that can do this for me but I want to learn pack / unpack.

my goal is I have a user input an ip address / subnet mask and then verify that it's valid.

one way i thought of doing it was "sprintf" and get a binary value of lets say 192.168.1.1 . that's an ok solution, but then i need to prepend the required amount of 0's t make it '8 bit'

that seems like a lot of unnecessary work when `pack` can put things in binary format. I used the `N` template i found http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html  my first goal was to get an ip address, convert it to binary, then convert it back.

```
$ip = "192.168.1.1";    
$bi = pack ("N*", $ip);    
print unpack("N*",$bi),"\n";
```

and the output i got was `192` so obviously i  don't understand what's going on here.

what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! ("`Argument "192.168.1.1" isn't numeric in pack`")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pack ("N*", $ip)` takes an integer out of $ip and puts it into network byte order.

What you want is packing the 4 decimal octets of the IP address as binary. No need to fiddle with endianness as the IP address string is already in big endian (The highest order byte is already at the start of the string).

I also changed the `*` to a `4`, IP addresses are always 4 octets long:

```
$ip = "192.168.1.1";    
$bi = pack "C4", split('\.', $ip);
print join('.', unpack("C4",$bi)), "\n";
```